# Cypress: cannot select option from an ajax call

Tags: ajax, cypress

Sorry for asking this. I'm quite new in using cypress. 
I have two selects. #firstSelect and #secondSelect.

- #firstSelect options would be filled up using ajax upon
  document.ready
- #secondSelect options would be filled up after    firstSelect got a
  value.

At first I tried using static values like

```
cy
.get("#firstSelect").select('1')
.get("#secondSelect").select('2')
```

This works fine, but when I put values dynamically.

```
cy.server()
cy.route('POST', 'url').as("secondSelect")

cy.get("#firstSelect").each( ($el, idxFs) => {

  cy.get('#firstSelect').select($el.get(0).value)
    .wait('@secondSelect').then( function(xhr) {
    //code in selecting a value for the secondSelect
    }
})
```

Was able to select a value in firstSelect.
Anything I do wrong on the dynamic part?
 Any other approach for this scenario will be a huge help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to assert that the following happens, and that it happens in order:

1) `#firstSelect` is populated

2) A post request occurs

3) `#secondSelect` is populated

---

This is relatively simple to do:

```
cy.server()
cy.route('POST', 'url').as("updateServer")

// Wait for #firstSelect to be populated, assumes #firstSelect is the surrounding <ul>
cy.get("#secondSelect").children().should("have.length", 10);

// Again, this assumes #firstSelect is the parent
cy.get("#firstSelect").children().each( ($el, idxFs) => {
    // Using .should() here makes Cypress retry the assertion until it succeeds or times out.
    cy.wrap($el).should('equal', 'someVal');
    cy.wrap($el).should($item => {
        expect($item).to.have.property("style");
        //...
    });
});

// Wait for post request. Takes advantage of automatic retries.
cy.wait('@updateServer');

// Wait for #secondSelect to be populated
cy.get("#firstSelect").children().should("have.length", 10);

cy.get("#secondSelect").children().each( ($el, idxFs) => {
    // Perfom assertions on each list item in #secondSelect...
});
```

It's possible I'm misunderstanding your question. If this is the case, please edit your post with more info about and code for the specific problem.